# Add Mobile Backend starter to existing project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

I've got a Google Cloud console project, which I use for Google Play Game Services. Now I've read [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2013/06/bootstrap-your-apps-cloud-services-with.html), talking about easily creating a mobile backend for your app. However, this only talks about creating a *new* project. I want to deploy the backend for my *existing* project.

Is that possible? How would I do that? Note that when I go to my project page in the Google Cloud Console, there is no "Getting Started" button, or "Deploy" button.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing project created from cloud console, then you can deploy the mobile backend starter for it from the project page. If you are not seeing the option, then possibly, it is collapsed as below:

[image: mobile backend starter option collapsed]

If you click that, you should be able to see the mobile backend option or photofeed app option, which are horizontally scrollable
[image: mobile backend starter deploy button]

Comment: The "Get started with sample applications" is not visible, nor the arrows to expand it

Comment: ok. seems may be that option is not getting enabled for projects created as an api console project. i think the option is coming by default only for cloud projects with a linked app engine project. if it suits you , please create a new cloud console project and then check for the deploy option. even if you try to add the backend starter project to your existing project, you will not be able to edit the backend .

Answer (score 0):

Note, we have changed the UI a bit in the Cloud Console.  But you can still deploy the mobile backend sample.  https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that as of this posting (4/10/14) the easiest way to do this is to just append /mobilesample to the main URL of your project, like so;

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/half~baked-UIswitch-538/mobilesample/
```

From there you just click the deploy button, and you're good. At least I was good. And I have no idea what I'm doing :P